# A way to combine Adobe AIR with .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, flash, air

I was wondering if there is a possibility to combine an AIR application with a WinForms Application?

**Example**

I've made some nice animated loading screens / splash screens with [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) and i want to use them with an .NET program, is that possible?

I don't want to simply call the program executable file (`program.exe`) within Adobe AIR (`Air.exe`). I want to use the textfields inside air, and as I click on Submit, I want AIR to pass the information to the .NET `C#` form and do stuff with that.

What is the proper way to do so, or what are alternative ways? (using `WPF` to embed a flash (`SWF`) inside `.NET`)

Comment: What is AIR?  Do you have a link?

Comment: @RQDQ [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) is a runtime that enables developers to package the same code into native apps for iPhone, iPad, Kindle Fire, Nook Tablet, and other Android™ devices, reaching the mobile app stores for over 500 million devices

Comment: yes, AIR is a flash based runtime from adobe

Comment: here's a example of AIR https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bKzsWH0sQHs

Comment: "I want to use the textfields inside air, and as I click on Submit, I want AIR to pass the information to the .NET C# form and do stuff with that." - this sounds like a pretty convoluted design. While there are valid use cases for automating a GUI app, the "good" ways of doing so tend to be heavily dependent on a platform; I doubt trying to do so from a platform-independent environment like AIR will be easy.

Comment: What you could do is create a platform-specific "helper" program that handles the automation in .NET, or even AutoIt, that can be invoked just by calling the executable and can perform the desired GUI actions on behalf of the AIR program. However, this makes the design somewhat brobdingnagian. Alternately, since these are splash screens, wouldn't it be possible to call them from your .NET program instead of the other way around? Maybe have the AIR program print the data it gathers to standard output and read it from the .NET program.

Comment: Personally, I'd drop the whole idea of an animated interactive splash screen to begin with. If your program loads slowly, just make it display something, anything, quicker. Like display a non-interactive screenshot of what the UI will look like, with a progress bar / spinner overlaid.

Comment: mhm i see it gets really complicated..., i think i should leave AIR and .NET for its own. what is with embeding animation ( swf, avi, mp4 ) in .NET and put the GUI controlls over the animation ( textbox, btn ) ? ( keep in mind that all the frames sould have transparent parts where pixelperfect clicks needs to be possible, to clicking on transparent part will focus the window / desktop behind it )

Answer (score 0):

Based on the content posted in this [tutorial](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/adobe-media-server/articles/first_im_app.html), I think that it's possible to use .NET with [Adobe AIR](http://www.adobe.com/products/air.html) yet I'm not really sure.

You might also like to take a look at [this](http://ajaxian.com/archives/commandproxy-integrating-air-and-net) which shows how to use `CommandProxy` to integrate AIR and .NET

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: Tutorial you mentioned uses C# on server side, not together with AIR app.

Comment: yeah , thats what i've just seen too. this solution is only a way of connection between them. i'm searching for a way of combining them. i know flash ( SWF ) can have a script access ( javascript, ... ) to call function inside flash and have a callback. but i only knew that this works in the browser. so dont know if AIR supports this too.

Comment: but i think a framework is one of the possible ways. i'm searching on it ^^

Comment: i have found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/770384/how-to-use-c-sharp-with-air and they say that i can embed the SWF inside an activeX object. but they do not say that code interactivity is possible between C# and as3